# Is Remote Bundling of resources on a CDN possible?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, bundle, cdn, system.web.optimization

I'm trying to move all my javascript and css (less files etc) to a separate site which will be hosted on a site that we will use as a CDN.

However I want to make use of MVC ScriptBundle and StyleBundle classes to tie into BundleTransformer.Less.

At first I just tried a test script bundle like so:

```
Bundle mainScript = new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/scripts/test.js", @CDNUrl + "lib/jquery/2.1.4/jquery-2.1.4.js");
bundles.Add(mainScript);
```

The issue here, is that if I am in debug mode or optimizations are off, no script is output because I didn't include anything.  And if I turn optimizations on it just drops the cdn link in a script tag.

Ideally I don't want to have to include the scripts and styles in the site (I could map a virtual directory to where they are on the cdn).

What I want to do is build all my bundles on the CDN, and just link to them via

```
<script src="//cdn.etc.com/bunles/xyzSiteScripts.js"></script>
```

However a minimized link get's generated like so:

```
<script src="/bundles/scripts/test2.js?v=SQINHU6JqPGF50s4ugWSC_sMpTAqiQhXWc8eDYzbyDg1"></script>
```

v on the query string is the cache buster.  I am considered that if I just link to them I will have to manually update all my links with new cache busters every time I chance one.

Is there a way to handle this already that I am missing?  From what I gather, if I move the bundling to the CDN itself, then I won't be able to use @Scripts or @Styles in my razor templates.

Comment: Thinking about this more, I could use a TT template to generate a Partial Razor view and automatically build the script links with cache busters on them by pulling the date times.. But then I need to know how the MVC Bundler is coming up with those version query strings.

Comment: So the cache buster is actually a SHA256 hash UrlTokenEncoded.  So I will try an approach where all the bundles are on the CDN and I will make a simple json service return the sha256 hashes for everything and I'll have my TT templates call that to build their script links.